# I have an SQL syntax error in graphQL when i hit the query using join monster

Tags: express-graphql

This is My Schema

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const joinMonster = require('join-monster');
const FilmDb  = require('../model/Films');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt,GraphQLSchema } = graphql;

const Films = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'films',

  fields: () => ({
    id: {
        type: GraphQLInt,

      },

      name: {
          type: GraphQLString,

      },
  })
})
Films._typeConfig = {
    sqlTable: 'films',
    uniqueKey: 'id'
  }

const QueryRoot = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    films: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Films),
      resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {
        return joinMonster.default(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {

            return FilmDb.query(sql).then(function(result) {

                return result;
              });

        })
      }
    }
  })
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryRoot
})
```

When I hit the below query

{
      films{
        id
      }
    }

It is showing me an error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.\"id\" AS \"id\"\nFROM films \"films\"' at line 1",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "films"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "films": null
  }
}
```

my SQL query what is generated in the terminal is

SELECT
  "films"."id" AS "id"
FROM films "films"

Here I m using nodejs and in DB using Sequelize
What is the error here?? I m unable to find exact error.

Comment: have you run this query in sql query console too `SELECT "films"."id" AS "id" FROM films "films"`?

Comment: I found the mistake. Thank you